# Meteor JS does not render page title of main template

Tags: html, templates, meteor

I am using a main template with a `{{> yield}}` statement to render my Meteor JS pages. This is how it looks like:

```
<template name="main">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/spacers.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {{> yield}}
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</template>
```

And with it, I render my actual pages e.q.:

```
<template name="home">
    HOME
</template>
```

This all is functional because I use [Iron Router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) like so:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: "main",
    notFoundTemplate: "404"
});

Router.route("/", function() {
    this.render("home");
});
```

The problem I face is that the page title isn't being rendered. I would expect the page title to be "Title" because I have defined `<head> -> <title>` to be "Title" (as you can see in my main template).

The weird thing here is that all the CSS does load, which indicates that the `<head>` section is - at least partially - rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `head` is rendered in a special process. Let's call it *bundling* for the lack of a better word. In that *bundling*-process the **contents** of all `body` and `head` elements are put into the HTML that will be served first. `iron-router` appends the contents of your template to the `body` after meteor is loaded on the client. These elements are only being searched for on the root level. The `link` tags are loaded, because most browsers (more or less) don't care where they occur.

I'd do something like this:

`client/main.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/spacers.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

`client/templates/main.html`

```
<template name="main">
    <div class="container">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```